# how to show modal popup in asp repeater control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have following code which binds the properties based on property id :

```
<form>
<!-- Main div -->
<div class="row">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProperties" runat="server">
 <HeaderTemplate>
 </HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="item col-md-4">
    <div class="price">
        <%# CustomFormat(Int32.Parse(Eval("budget").ToString())) %>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    <h3>
        <%# DLResale.getBedNameByID( Int32.Parse(Eval("beds").ToString())) %> <%# DLResale.getConfigNameByID( Int32.Parse(Eval("propertyConfig").ToString())) %>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        <small><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <%# Eval("locationStr") %>, <%# Eval("cityStr") %></small>
    </h3>

    <ul class="amenities">
        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <a id="ViewDetails" class="btn btn-default-color btn-sm view-price"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>View Details</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>

<!-- Modal Popup-->
<div id="m-request-details" >
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDetail" runat="server" Class="btn btn-default-color btn-sm" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnDetail_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup" />
</div>
</div>

<form>
```

The javascript code which opens the modal popup is as follows :

```
$("#ViewDetails").click(function () {
                console.log("modal");
                $('#m-request-details').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
            })
```

However there are 10 properties on page, but when i click on view details, the popup opens for the first property only & not for the other properties.

The C# repeater binds the 10 properties as data-columns are same for each and every property i.e. budget, beds, location.

Can anyone figure out why modal popup is being opened for the first property only and not for the rest ones????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a id="ViewDetails" class="btn btn-default-color btn-sm view-price"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>View Details</a>
```

Your problem is with the id of the  tag. You propably generate more than one links and they do not have the same id thats why `$("#ViewDetails").click(function ()` Does not work.

There are several ways you can get the list item click function see example below:

```
 <ul class="amenities">
        <li style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <a class="btn btn-default-color btn-sm view-price"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>View Details</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

$("ul.amenities li").click(function () {
                console.log("modal");
                $('#m-request-details').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
            })
```

Comment: Glad I could Help